# How can I fix a 'ValueError' in my GridSearchCV model with SimpleImputer() and GradientBoostingClassifier() in Python?

Tags: python, data-science

clf = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(),
GradientBoostingClassifier())

params = {
'simpleimputer__strategy': ['mean', 'median'],
'gardientboostingclassifier__n_estimators': range(20,31,5),
'gardientboostingclassifier__max_depth': range(2,5)
}

model = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid= params , cv=5 , n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)

## Fit model to over-sampled training data

model.fit(X_train_over,y_train_over)

iget an error

ValueError: Invalid parameter 'gardientboostingclassifier' for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('simpleimputer', SimpleImputer()),
('gradientboostingclassifier', GradientBoostingClassifier())]). Valid parameters are: ['memory', 'steps', 'verbose'].

iget an error

ValueError: Invalid parameter 'gardientboostingclassifier' for estimator Pipeline(steps=[('simpleimputer', SimpleImputer()),
('gradientboostingclassifier', GradientBoostingClassifier())]). Valid parameters are: ['memory', 'steps', 'verbose'].

Comment: "gardient" -> "gradient"